# Hyper-V: Move guest storage on same HD faster (without copying)

Tags: virtual-machine, hyper-v, vhd, windows-server-2016, hyper-v-manager

I like putting VMs into separate folders for better overview of what is where, e. g.

```
D:\VM\MyVM1
D:\VM\SomeVM2
```

So often (especially with Replicas, where there is no option on where to put it) I move VMs after creating them - on the same hd, just to a different folder.

The default mechanism seems to work by copying all files, which is reasonably slow, where a move command should work just as well.

Is there any (simple, without going to the file system oneself and hassling with locked files) way to achieve this and speed the process up when reorganizing on the same HD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible.

1. Shut down your VM then stop the Hyper-V management service (from management console)
2. Browse to the folder `“C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V\Virtual Machines”`where you will find fake-link file to the XML settings file of the VM with the same name just rename it to .old .
3. Move the VM to the new location
4. After the VM is moved then open a new command prompt as an administrator and then type the command:

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Hyper-V\Virtual Machines>mklink 0B142A56-4B3F-4AE5-88E5-AC21B33CE290.xml "\0B142A56-4B3F-4AE5-88E5-AC21B33CE290.xml"

6. You need to give the local users full control over this created file. Do that with the security tab.
7. Start back the service and you're done.

Comment: Thank you! It is not quite the solution I want though since I have to shutdown all VMs and stop the service. But apart from that, I think it is simple enough, especially for bulk moves.

Comment: Well, there's nothing much we can do when it comes to data re-organization when a VM is active.